# How to run my robocorp's project(robot framework) on end-user(clients)'s computer without using robocorp control room?

Tags: python, windows, robotframework, rpa

So for now, I have already done developing my rpa automation code by using robocorp in vscode, how can i make the robocorp project could be runnable on the end-user's computer without using vscode/control room?

I try to watch on the forum, but seems that there is no answer for my question. So i wish someone can help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Idea 1

If you are using python to develop, you can create a new file called run.py in the root of your project (same level as tests). Then import your robot_name and call what you need from tasks:

```py
import robot_name
robot_name.tasks.one_task_name()
```

Then, you can call the code with something like (where `3a1f7d2_b1f3c24_6cd60f16` is the name of your conda space created by robocorp):

```bash
C:\ProgramData\robocorp\ht\3a1f7d2_b1f3c24_6cd60f16\python.exe .\run.py
```

###### Example:

Example of code structure with `robot_name == f5` and `one_task_name() == vpn_connection()`
[image: Example of task call]

## Idea2

You can also call RCC to run the robot. In this case, you'll need to be in the directory of your robot (where 'robot.yaml' is).

```
cd yourRobotDir/
C:\Users\UserName\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-1.19.0-win32-x64\bin\rcc.exe run
```

The trick is then to include your robot directory in the path. If you want your robot to be system agnostic, you can add the path in the 'task.py' file by adding this in the begining:

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/../')
```